# simple Jquery hover enlarge

Tags: jquery, hover, scale, image-enlarge

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I'm trying to create a very simple hover-enlarge plugin with Jquery using the scale function. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content img").toggle("scale",{
      percent: "80%"
    },0);
$('#content img').hover(function() {
    $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(this).toggle("scale",{
      percent: "90%"
    },500);

}, function() {
    $(this).toggle("scale",{
      percent: "80%"
    },500);

});
});
```

Here's a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/8ECh6/

Here's the page: http://samples.zcardna.com/health.html

If somone knows where I've gone wrong that would awesome!
THANKS!

Comment: hi @A-frame, you get quicker help if you post a link to a JSFiddle with your code in it. (http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: What happens (or doesn't happen)? Are you getting errors? Post your HTML as well.

Comment: @j08691 Nothing happens. Here is the simple landing page I'm working on: http://samples.zcardna.com/health.html

Comment: @blurfus [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8ECh6/)

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well I'm not exactly sure why your code is not working because I usually follow a different approach when trying to accomplish something similar.

But your code is erroring out.. There seems to be an issue with the way you are using `scale` I got the jQuery to actually execute by changing your code to the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').hover(function() {
        $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
        $(this).toggle({
          effect: "scale",
          percent: "90%"
        },200);
    }, function() {
         $(this).toggle({
           effect: "scale",
           percent: "80%"
         },200);

    });
});
```

But I have always done it by using `CSS` to setup my scaling and transition..

Here is an example, hopefully it helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').hover(function() {
        $("#content").addClass('transition');

    }, function() {
        $("#content").removeClass('transition');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y4yAP/

Comment: Use `#content:hover` in CSS and you don't have to use jQuery/JS at all... see http://jsfiddle.net/en30ajh0/ (toggling class on hover with JavaScript seems pretty redundant)

Comment: @Trevor i needed some call back after transition done. i want to hide image after transition and show div with some detail something like http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/index10.html

Comment: @anam Sorry what your asking might be best answered in a new question.  If you have created a question and don't get an answer right away message me the link to your question and I'll take a crack at it.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 1 image on the page that you like to enlarge, name the id's for instance  "content1", "content2", "content3", etc. Then extend the script with this, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=content]").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('transition');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('transition');
    });
});
```

Edit:
Change the "#content" CSS to: img[id^=content]  to remain having the transition effects.

Answer (score 0):

To create simple hover enlarge plugin, try this.
[(DEMO)](http://jsfiddle.net/U7pYC/)

**HTML**

```
     <div id="content">
     <img src="http://www.freevectorgallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Vintage-Microphone- 11395-large.jpg" style="width:50%;" />
     </div>
```

**js**

```
        $(function () {
          $('#content img').hover(function () {
          $(this).toggle(function () {
          $(this).width('70%');
                   });
              });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo Link**](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/jquery/jquery-zoom-thumbnails/)

**[Tutorial Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/image-thumbnail-zoom-effect-on-mouse-hover-using-jquery/)**

This will show original dimensions of Image on Hover using jQuery custom code

**HTML**

```
        <ul class="thumb">
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/1.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/2.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/3.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/4.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/5.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/6.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/7.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/8.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <div class="thumbnail-wrap" style="background-image:url(./images/9.jpg)"></div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
    ul.thumb {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 360px;
        margin: 80px;
    }

    ul.thumb li {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        /* Set the absolute positioning base coordinate */
        width: 110px;
        height: 110px;
    }

    ul.thumb li .thumbnail-wrap {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        /* Set the small thumbnail size */
        -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
        /* IE Fix for Bicubic Scaling */
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        -webkit-box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 40px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 40px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
        box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 40px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);

    }

    ul.thumb li .thumbnail-wrap.hover {
        -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 1px 22px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        -moz-box-shadow: -2px 1px 22px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
        box-shadow: -2px 1px 22px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }

    .thumnail-zoomed-wrapper {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        z-index: 99;
    }

    .thumbnail-zoomed-image {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 12%;
    }

    .thumbnail-zoomed-image img {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .close-image-zoom {
        z-index: 10;
        float: right;
        margin: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
        var perc = 40;
        $("ul.thumb li").hover(function () {
            $("ul.thumb li").find(".thumbnail-wrap").css({
                "z-index": "0"
            });
            $(this).find(".thumbnail-wrap").css({
                "z-index": "10"
            });
            var imageval = $(this).find(".thumbnail-wrap").css("background-image").slice(5);
            var img;
            var thisImage = this;
            img = new Image();
            img.src = imageval.substring(0, imageval.length - 2);
            img.onload = function () {
                var imgh = this.height * (perc / 100);
                var imgw = this.width * (perc / 100);
                $(thisImage).find(".thumbnail-wrap").addClass("hover").stop()
                    .animate({
                        marginTop: "-" + (imgh / 4) + "px",
                        marginLeft: "-" + (imgw / 4) + "px",
                        width: imgw + "px",
                        height: imgh + "px"
                    }, 200);
            }
        }, function () {
            var thisImage = this;
            $(this).find(".thumbnail-wrap").removeClass("hover").stop()
                .animate({
                    marginTop: "0",
                    marginLeft: "0",
                    top: "0",
                    left: "0",
                    width: "100px",
                    height: "100px",
                    padding: "5px"
                }, 400, function () {});
        });

        //Show thumbnail in fullscreen
        $("ul.thumb li .thumbnail-wrap").click(function () {

            var imageval = $(this).css("background-image").slice(5);
            imageval = imageval.substring(0, imageval.length - 2);
            $(".thumbnail-zoomed-image img").attr({
                src: imageval
            });
            $(".thumnail-zoomed-wrapper").fadeIn();
            return false;
        });

        //Close fullscreen preview
        $(".thumnail-zoomed-wrapper .close-image-zoom").click(function () {
            $(".thumnail-zoomed-wrapper").hide();
            return false;
        });
```

[image]