# Changing image size during mouse hover

Tags: html

I am currently trying to make it so that if i hover over the `li`, the image changes its size. I managed to pull out a code from a website that changes the image size if i hover over the `img` which looks like the following:

```
<div class="profiles">
    <ul>
        <li class="portraitsLeft" id="one" align="left">
            <a href="../project/profile1.html">
                <img src="../project/images/portraits/img1.jpg" width="100" onmouseover="this.width=150;" onmouseout="this.width=100" align="middle" alt="Img1"/>
            </a> 
            Character 1
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What i don't understand is what `this` is pointing at. I assumed it points at `img` but it doesn't seem to work. How should I change the code so that i can change the image size when i hover over the `li` or `a` instead of `this`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "this" is referring to the element currently being referred to by the event....in this case the onmouseover event is referring to "this" image that is being moused over

Comment: if you prefer a zoom effect -- http://jsfiddle.net/y4yAP/ -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078250/simple-jquery-hover-enlarge

Comment: Are you sure the above isn't working? Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jVeju/2/). It validates what you did and works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need for CSS(although it is cleaner) in this case. You can do this using a `name` attribute.

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/OrteliusWorldMap.jpeg" width="150" height="100" name="OrteliusWorldMap"
onmouseover="OrteliusWorldMap.width='300';OrteliusWorldMap.height='200';"
onmouseout="OrteliusWorldMap.width='150';OrteliusWorldMap.height='100';" />
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jVeju/).

EDIT:

You can now change it anywhere you like thanks to the `name` attribute.

```
<div class="profiles">
    <ul>
        <li class="portraitsLeft" id="one" align="left">
            <a href="google.com" onmouseover="OrteliusWorldMap.width=150;" onmouseout="OrteliusWorldMap.width=100">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/OrteliusWorldMap.jpeg" width="100" name="OrteliusWorldMap">
            </a> 
            Character 1
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle Link.](http://jsfiddle.net/jVeju/3/)

The issue with trying to use `this` elsewhere is that `this` will try to reference the current HTML element. See the following for more information on [`this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) and how the [onMouseOver event works](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470771).

Comment: Thank you! This really helped + I learned something new and handy today!

Answer (score 4):

Why not use `CSS`?

```
<img id="image" src="../project/images/portraits/img1.jpg" align="middle" alt="Img1"/>

#image{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}

#image:hover{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PwT9E/)**

Or you can change your code to this:

```
<img id="image" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" onMouseOver="this.style.width='200px'" onMouseOut="this.style.width='100px'" alt="Img1"/>
```

Use `this.style.width='200px'`

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PwT9E/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to CSS, you could go the jQuery route:

```
$("img").mouseover(function() {
    $("img").css({ width: '150px', height: '150px' });
});
```

This would also allow you to add some animations on hover if you wanted that.

This would require that you include the jQuery package in your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:

```
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/OrteliusWorldMap.jpeg" alt="test" />

img {
    width: 100px;
}
img:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v3qmE/345/)

Comment: first of all, thank you for your help. however, i think that this answer isnt really what i needed help on (sorry if the question wasnt specific enough). from your code, i think that it only changes the image size when i hover over the img if im not mistaken. I wanted to know how to change it so that a specific image thats inside the li changes its size if i hover over any part of the <a> or <li>. i edited the question so that its more specific. thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
You can try using Javascript, without using any "this" keyword.

<html>
 <body>
    <ul>
       <li>
          <a href="" onmouseover="img_increase()" onmouseout="img_decrease()">Character</a>         
          <img id="image" src="../project/images/portraits/img1.jpg" width="100" >          
       </li>
    </ul>

   <script>

        function img_increase()
        {
            document.getElementById("image").style.width="150px";
        } 

        function img_decrease()
        {
           document.getElementById("image").style.width="100px";
        }

    </script>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

'this' is a keyword used by most proramming languages including java and javascript.
'this' keyword is used to point the current object. 'this' is always a reference to the object on which the method(function) was called.